# Creating Opportunity from ServiceContract including line items

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem

I have the following apex code to create an Opportunity from a Service Contract:

```
public class serviceContractOpportunities 
    {

         public PageReference createOpportunities() 
         {
            Map<Id, Opportunity> opps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
            for(ServiceContract sc: [SELECT ID, Legal_Entity__c, ServiceContract.Contact.Id, Name, AccountId, EndDate FROM ServiceContract WHERE EndDate = This_quarter AND Terminated__c = False])
            {
                opps.put(sc.Id, new Opportunity(
                    Name = sc.Name,
                    AccountId = sc.AccountId,
                    Order_Type__c = 'AMS',
                    Contact__c = sc.Contact.Id,
                    StageName = 'Value Proposition',
                    CloseDate = sc.EndDate,
                    Related_Service_Contract_del__c  = sc.Id,
                    Legal_Entity__c = sc.Legal_Entity__c,
                    System_Type__c = 'Maintenance Renewal',
                    Type = 'Existing Business',
                    LeadSource = 'Maintenance'
                ));
            }

            insert opps.values();

            OpportunityLineItem[] lines = new OpportunityLineItem[0];

            for(ContractLineItem cli: [select ServiceContract.Name, Pricebookentry.Name, ServiceContractId, Quantity, TotalPrice, PricebookEntryId FROM ContractLineItem WHERE ServiceContractId = :opps.keyset()]) 
            {
                lines.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
                OpportunityId = opps.get(cli.ServiceContractId).Id,
                Quantity = cli.Quantity,
                TotalPrice = cli.TotalPrice,
                Description = 'Annual Maintenance ' +  cli.Pricebookentry.Name,
                PriceBookEntryId = cli.PriceBookEntryId
                ));
            }
            insert lines;
            return null; 
        } 
    }
```

Which works great. However, the process here is a bit different. Since an opportunity is invoiced through another system, it needs to look in a certain way in order to be uploaded as a CSV file into our financial system.

In the end, all products in the opportunity should be of product code 'ZY-SLA'. In addition, three extra lines need to be added to the opportunity, also with product code 'ZY-SLA', and different descriptions.

A complete opportunity should look as following:

[image: Opportunity]

Where the first three are the aforementioned descriptions, and the last four lines are the products from the ServiceContract.

How can I add the three dummy lines, and how can I set all the products to 'ZY-SLA'?

Comment: How you are receiving those three dummy line items?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The three dummy line items should be in all opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to insert dummy line items.

Pass the Opportunity Id and Set of product ids to this method.

Feel free to change according to your need, I have given an approach to insert `OpportunityLineItems`.

```
private void insertOpportunityLineItems(Id opportunityId, Set<Id> productIdSet)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> listInsertOpptyLineItem = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    Map<Id,PriceBookEntry> prodPriceBookMap = new Map<Id,PriceBookEntry>();

    Id pricebookId = null;

    //retrieve the Id from Standard price book.
    List<Pricebook2> lstPriceBook = [   SELECT Id 
                                        FROM Pricebook2 
                                        WHERE isStandard = true 
                                        LIMIT 1];
    //retrieve the standard price book id
    if(Test.isRunningTest())
    {
        pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    }
    else if (lstPriceBook.size()>0)
    {
        pricebookId=lstPriceBook[0].Id;
    }

    //retrieve the price book entries of the products
    Map<Id,PriceBookEntry> priceBookEntryMap = new Map<Id,PriceBookEntry>([ SELECT  Id, 
                                                        Product2Id, 
                                                        Product2.Id, 
                                                        Product2.Name,
                                                        UnitPrice 
                                                FROM    PriceBookEntry 
                                                WHERE 
                                                        Product2Id in:productIdSet
                                                AND     Pricebook2Id =:pricebookId]);

    //create list of line items
    for(PriceBookEntry pbk:priceBookEntryMap.values())
    {
        OpportunityLineItem opptyLineItem = new OpportunityLineItem();
        opptyLineItem.OpportunityId = opportunityId;
        opptyLineItem.PricebookEntryId = pbk.Id;                
        listInsertOpptyLineItem.add(opptyLineItem);
    }

    //finally perform insert operation
    insert listInsertOpptyLineItem;         
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Santanu! I wasn't expecting so much code to be honest. What I perhaps failed to mention was that ZY-SLA is already a Product in our Pricebook? I will try to understand the code (quite new to APEX) and see if I can make it work, thanks!

Comment: I have given a approach to create lineItems, feel free to change according to your need

Comment: I have updated my code, to make it concise